Files disappearing on USB
I have a SanDisk USB drive as a backup for my laptop and when I tried to backup some files, one was 4.7gbs and I got an error saying the file was too large and I needed to format the drive to ntfs.  I cleared off the USB and backed up some files on an SD card (not enough room on my laptop for everything) and formatted the USB.  Once finished, I started putting files back on the USB and, when I got to the SD card, it was corrupted and I use DMDE to recover all the files on the SD card.  I then transferred what I recovered from the SD card to the USB.  I then started renaming the recovered files on the USB (the names of the files were all replaced with f and a series of numbers by DMDE) and everything was going fine until I hit "enter" to finish renaming one file, and it and 130 files in the folder disappeared.
I went to the command prompt and cd to the folder on the USB and used the ls command.  The USB says there are 30 files in the folder, but only 24 are visible in the folder and in the command prompt.  I double checked to make sure hidden files are visible then I did a search on the USB and laptop to see if the files were moved.  The files weren't found so I named a file the same name as one that disappeared and moved it to the USB folder I was working on.  I then got an error saying the file already existed and whether I wanted to rename or overwrite the file.  I tried both and the files still disappear.  I also renamed one of the files that was visible and it too disappeared as soon as I hit "enter" to rename it.
So, in sort, the files seems to still be in the folder on the USB, but are not visible and are not showing up on the "properties" of the folder or in the command prompt.  Restarting the computer, and unmounting and mounting the USB hasn't helped.  I've used GParted to run a check on the USB and no errors were found.  Any idea what else I can do to make these files visible again?  I'm using Kubuntu 22.04 and I'm still getting the hang of using linux.

Could be the filesystems on (both?) USB and SD card are corrupted -- maybe caused by the hardware itself just wearing out.  Neither USB (sticks?) nor SD cards are meant for heavy usage, backup is fine, but they do wear out. try fsck to check the filesystem, and consider getting another backup solution -- like an SSD/harddisk in an enclosure.

Very possibly the SD card has failed and is now read only.  It may have written some of the files before it failed, but the rest were only in cache and didn't actually get written out.

Are you using Windows formats like FAT32 or NTFS? You should be using LInux formats like ext4 for Linux backup or copy of files. Windows FAT32 cannot store a file over 4GB and Microsoft will set hibernation flag on its formats which prevent Linux NTFS driver from properly seeing the file system. Sound like Windows issues.
